# Finding index of largest negative and smallest positive element in array

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have an array as follows:

```
import numpy as np    
Arr = np.array([-10, -8, -8, -6, -2, 2, 4, 19])
```

How do I find the `index` of largest negative and smallest positive number?

i.e in the above example index of -2 and 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try, for max of negative:

```
list(Arr).index(max(Arr[Arr<0]))
```

In above, `Arr[Arr<0]` will get all numbers less than 0 or negative and applying `max` to the list will give max of negative. Then, it can be used with `index` to get the index of number in list.

And for min of positive:

```
list(Arr).index(min(Arr[Arr>0]))
```