# How to find maximum negative and minimum positive number in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max, minimum

I am given an array containing both positive and negative numbers.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([-10.2, -5.3, -2.1, 0, 1.2, 3.4])
```

I would like to find the index corresponding to the maximum negative number and to a minimum positive number. In the above, my expected outcome is `2` and `4`. Is there any `numpy` trick to achieve this? I have found a solution in this link, but I would like to know how this could be done through `numpy` functions:
[Finding index of largest negative and smallest positive element in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224895/finding-index-of-largest-negative-and-smallest-positive-element-in-array)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the input is sorted?

Comment: No, it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Replace non negative values with `-inf`, then use `argmax` to find the largest negative:

```
np.where(arr < 0, arr, -np.inf).argmax()
# 2
```

Similarly replace non positive values with `inf` then use `argmin` to find the smallest positive:

```
np.where(arr > 0, arr, np.inf).argmin()
# 4
```

Comment: Or replace with `nan` and use `nanargmax` and `nanargmin`.  But that's not much different than using `inf`.

Comment: @Psidom Is using Numpy functions as in your answer faster or  doing it with lists as mentioned in the answer tagged in the question faster?

Answer (score 1):

If your array is always sorted (as in the provided example), then:

```
# input
Out[66]: array([-10.2,  -5.3,  -2.1,   0. ,   1.2,   3.4])

# obtain a `signed` boolean mask 
In [75]: sign_mask = np.sign(arr)

# compute derivative and obtain index for max_negative element
In [76]: max_neg_idx = np.where(np.diff(sign_mask, append=1) == 1)[0][0]

# add +2 to that to get index for min_positive element
In [77]: min_pos_idx = max_neg_idx + 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar type of problem and this was my approach:

```
arr=np.array([-10.2, -5.3, -2.1, 0, 1.2, 3.4])

#Filtering for all the negative values and getting the min of them
print('Threshold for Min val',np.where(arr==[max(arr[arr<0])]))

#Filtering for all the positive values and getting the max of them
print('Threshold for Max val',np.where(val==[min(arr[arr>0])]))
```